# Convert shoutcast stream to playable samples in Python?

Tags: python, stream, sample, shoutcast, audio-player

I have a shoutcat radio station and now want to build a player for it. I know how to "get" thet stream from the server, thanks a lot to bobince , but I am not sure how to convert that stream into playable samples. How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from what I can read on python, try [this](http://pyaudiere.org/) page. If that doesn't work, try the PythonInMusic article on the python wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Shoutcast streams are typically (but not always) MP3.  To get playable samples, you have to decode the stream's MP3 data.

Have you seen the resource at http://codeboje.de/playing-mp3-stream-python/?  Looks like a simple solution, but requires an awful lot of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few possibilities for MP3 decoding under Python. [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/) is one I've had some success with in the past (but for which development seems to have stopped). It's not just an MP3 decoder though, but a playback interface with support for many audio and video formats via ffmpeg. There's also [pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) which seems to have come back to life recently (haven't tried it yet).

Then there's [PyGame](http://pygame.org/) can also play MP3, though this is a pretty small part of what it does. [pymad](http://spacepants.org/src/pymad/) is more lightweight possibility, being a direct interface to the libmad decoder library. And then there's always the possibility of handing the task off to an external multimedia library such as DirectShow, or GStreamer ([via gst-python](http://www.gstreamer.net/modules/gst-python.html))...