# Strange internet radio format

Tags: stream, format, media, internet-radio

I need to write an application that will be able to receive this radio stream: http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com:80/
As trivial as it may sound I have not idea what streaming format they use. Any ideas how can I find out?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the stream is presented in the MIME-type audio\mpeg, so it's probably an MP3 stream--that's relatively standard for SHOUTcast streams, of which your URL is one.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Receive" the radio stream. If you're looking to make a player/radio utility, I'd check out something like tRio, which is open source, and could serve as a jumping-off point for you rolling your own player. With regards to rolling your own, I've done something similar with MP3 streams (in Python), but not for SHOUTcast. The SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187552/how-do-i-capture-an-mp3-stream-with-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881230/convert-shoutcast-stream-to-playable-samples-in-python) were helpful in my efforts.

If by "Receive" you mean "capture to a file" (i.e. rip), you might consider writing a wrapper around a commandline program like [flcy](http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/fIcy/).

Comment: This is linked from one of those questions, and it was really useful: http://codeboje.de/playing-mp3-stream-python/

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the BBC, depending on your location, there is a good chance that you can't receive the stream. As long as you're in the UK they offer quite a lot of streams (audio, video), but outside, most of those are not accessable.

I just fiddled a bit with it (from the Netherlands), and this is what I get:

```
E:\tmp>wget.exe http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com/listen.pls
--00:56:25--  http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com/listen.pls
           => `listen.pls'
Resolving mp32.bbc.streamuk.com... 194.50.90.138
Connecting to mp32.bbc.streamuk.com|194.50.90.138|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [audio/x-scpls]

    [ <=>                                              ] 70            --.--K/s

00:56:30 (2.89 MB/s) - `listen.pls' saved [70]


E:\tmp>type listen.pls
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=1
File1=http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com:8020/


E:\tmp>c:wget.exe http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com:8020/
--00:57:04--  http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com:8020/
           => `index.html'
Resolving mp32.bbc.streamuk.com... 194.50.90.138
Connecting to mp32.bbc.streamuk.com|194.50.90.138|:8020... failed: Connection refused.
```

The `connection refused` speaks volumes. The status page at http://mp32.bbc.streamuk.com/ shows that the maximum number of connection has not yet been reached so most likely it has to do with a digital export restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you shouldn't be stealing the stream. If you asked BBC Worldservice nicely I am sure that be able to accommodate as their remit is make their streams widely available.

In case you're wondering its a mp3 stream. Just go to the world service site and there are pages describing how to listen. I prefer VLC...

its a 32 kbps mp3 shoutcast stream btw.